# Reduce a tree by recursively rolling up the parent's child nodes

Tags: javascript, tree, reduce, traversal

Attempting to reduce a flat list of items (each with a list of their own statuses) into a tree, where the status of the child node influences the parent.

```js
const Status = {
  UNKNOWN : { name: 'UNKNOWN' , priority: 0 },
  DEBUG   : { name: 'DEBUG'   , priority: 1 },
  INFO    : { name: 'INFO'    , priority: 2 },
  WARNING : { name: 'WARNING' , priority: 3 },
  ERROR   : { name: 'ERROR'   , priority: 4 },
};

const { UNKNOWN, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR } = Status;

const maxStatus = (statuses) =>
  statuses.reduce((max, curr) =>
    curr.priority > max.priority
      ? curr
      : max, UNKNOWN);

class Node {
  constructor({ id, parentId, status }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.status = status ?? UNKNOWN;
    this.children = [];
  }
};

const buildTree = (items) => {
  const
    root = new Node({ id: 0, parentId: null }),
    nodeList = { 0 : root };
  items.forEach(({ id, parentId, data }) => {
    if (!nodeList[id]) {
      nodeList[id] = new Node({
        id,
        parentId,
        status: maxStatus(data)
      });
    } else {
      Object.assign(nodeList[id], {
        parentId,
        status: maxStatus(data)
      });
    }
    if (!nodeList[parentId]) {
      nodeList[parentId] = new Node({ id: parentId });
    }
    nodeList[parentId].children.push(nodeList[id]);
  });
  return root;
};

const calculateStatus = (tree) => {
  let status = UNKNOWN;
  if (tree.children.length) {
    tree.children.forEach(child => {
      const localMax = calculateStatus(child);
      status = maxStatus([ status, localMax ]);
    });
    tree.status = status;
  }
}

const printNode = (node, depth) => {
  const indent = '  '.repeat(depth);
  const { id, status: { name } } = node;
  console.log(`${indent}${id} ${name}`);
  node.children.forEach(child =>
    printNode(child, depth + 1));
}

const printTree = (tree) => printNode(tree, 0);

const items = [
  { id:  1, parentId: 0, data: [ ] },
  { id:  2, parentId: 0, data: [ DEBUG, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  3, parentId: 0, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  4, parentId: 1, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  5, parentId: 1, data: [ DEBUG ] },
  { id:  6, parentId: 1, data: [ WARNING ] },
  { id:  7, parentId: 2, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  8, parentId: 7, data: [ DEBUG ] },
  { id:  9, parentId: 8, data: [ ] },
  { id: 10, parentId: 3, data: [ ERROR, ERROR ] },
]; 

const tree = buildTree(items);

printTree(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Expected output

```
0 ERROR
  1 WARNING
    4 INFO
    5 DEBUG
    6 WARNING
  2 INFO
    7 INFO
      8 DEBUG
        9 UNKNOWN
  3 ERROR
    10 ERROR
```

### Visual flow

Here is a graphical representation of the algorithm:

#### Initial state

The initial status shows each node as `UNKNOWN`.

[image: initial state]

#### Before traversal

Before the tree is traversed, each node has a pre-calculated status based on its data.

[image: before traversal]

#### After traversal

While traversing the tree (recursively) in a post-order traversal strategy, each node asks its children what their maximum status is.

[image: after traversal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues, both in `calculateStatus`:

1. It lacks a return statement, and so the recursive call will always return `undefined`. It should end with `return status;`
2. The initial value of `status` should not be `UNKNOWN`. When at a leaf, and `tree.children.length` is zero, you don't want to return `UNKNOWN`, but the actual `status` property value of the node. So start with `let status = tree.status`

Corrected:

```
const calculateStatus = (tree) => {
  let status = tree.status; // <--
  if (tree.children.length) {
    tree.children.forEach(child => {
      const localMax = calculateStatus(child);
      status = maxStatus([ status, localMax ]);
    });
    tree.status = status;
  }
  return status; // <--
}
```

And of course, you need to call `calculateStatus` in the main code.

```js
const Status = {
  UNKNOWN : { name: 'UNKNOWN' , priority: 0 },
  DEBUG   : { name: 'DEBUG'   , priority: 1 },
  INFO    : { name: 'INFO'    , priority: 2 },
  WARNING : { name: 'WARNING' , priority: 3 },
  ERROR   : { name: 'ERROR'   , priority: 4 },
};

const { UNKNOWN, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR } = Status;

const maxStatus = (statuses) => {
  return statuses.reduce((max, curr) =>
    curr.priority > max.priority
      ? curr
      : max, UNKNOWN);
};
class Node {
  constructor({ id, parentId, status }) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.status = status ?? UNKNOWN;
    this.children = [];
  }
};

const buildTree = (items) => {
  const
    root = new Node({ id: 0, parentId: null }),
    nodeList = { 0 : root };
  items.forEach(({ id, parentId, data }) => {
    if (!nodeList[id]) {
      nodeList[id] = new Node({
        id,
        parentId,
        status: maxStatus(data)
      });
    } else {
      Object.assign(nodeList[id], {
        parentId,
        status: maxStatus(data)
      });
    }
    if (!nodeList[parentId]) {
      nodeList[parentId] = new Node({ id: parentId });
    }
    nodeList[parentId].children.push(nodeList[id]);
  });
  return root;
};

const calculateStatus = (tree) => {
  let status = tree.status; // <--
  if (tree.children.length) {
    tree.children.forEach(child => {
      const localMax = calculateStatus(child);
      status = maxStatus([ status, localMax ]);
    });
    tree.status = status;
  }
  return status; // <--
}

const printNode = (node, depth) => {
  const indent = '  '.repeat(depth);
  const { id, status: { name } } = node;
  console.log(`${indent}${id} ${name}`);
  node.children.forEach(child =>
    printNode(child, depth + 1));
}

const printTree = (tree) => printNode(tree, 0);

const items = [
  { id:  1, parentId: 0, data: [ ] },
  { id:  2, parentId: 0, data: [ DEBUG, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  3, parentId: 0, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  4, parentId: 1, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  5, parentId: 1, data: [ DEBUG ] },
  { id:  6, parentId: 1, data: [ WARNING ] },
  { id:  7, parentId: 2, data: [ INFO, DEBUG ] },
  { id:  8, parentId: 7, data: [ DEBUG ] },
  { id:  9, parentId: 8, data: [ ] },
  { id: 10, parentId: 3, data: [ ERROR, ERROR ] },
]; 

const tree = buildTree(items);
calculateStatus(tree); // <--
printTree(tree);
```

Comment: I ended up creating a `Tree` class to do most of the work. Via: [Gist 94dd15aa](https://gist.github.com/rmkane/94dd15aa134c901a06181e57c20090d1)

Comment: I left a comment.

Comment: That does seem simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which treats your tree as immutable (and built out of plain JS objects, not constructed `Node`s) can use a simpler recursion for the core of your `buildTree` and `calculateStatus` functions.  We could write it like this:

```js
const Status = {UNKNOWN: {name: 'UNKNOWN', priority: 0}, DEBUG: {name: 'DEBUG', priority: 1}, INFO: {name: 'INFO', priority: 2}, WARNING: {name: 'WARNING', priority: 3}, ERROR: {name: 'ERROR', priority: 4}}
const {UNKNOWN, DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR} = Status

const maxStatus = (statuses) => statuses .reduce (
  (max, curr) => curr .priority > max .priority ? curr : max, 
  UNKNOWN
)

const buildForest = (items, target) =>
  items .filter (({parentId}) => parentId == target) .map (({id, parentId, data}) => ({
    id, 
    parentId, 
    status: maxStatus (data), 
    children: buildForest (items, id)
  }))

// Assumes there really is a single root.
const buildTree = (items) => 
  ({id: 0, parentId: null, status: UNKNOWN, children: buildForest (items, 0)})

const calculateStatus = (node, children = node .children .map (c => calculateStatus (c))) => ({
  ...node,
  status: maxStatus ([node .status, ...children .map (c => c .status)]),
  children,
})

const printNode = (node, depth) => {
  const indent = '  '.repeat(depth);
  const { id, status: { name } } = node;
  console.log(`${indent}${id} ${name}`)
  node.children.forEach(child =>
    printNode(child, depth + 1))
}

const printTree = (tree) => printNode (tree, 0)

const items = [{id: 1, parentId: 0, data: []}, {id: 2, parentId: 0, data: [DEBUG, DEBUG]}, {id: 3, parentId: 0, data: [INFO, DEBUG]}, {id: 4, parentId: 1, data: [INFO, DEBUG]}, {id: 5, parentId: 1, data: [DEBUG]}, {id: 6, parentId: 1, data: [WARNING]}, {id: 7, parentId: 2, data: [INFO, DEBUG]}, {id: 8, parentId: 7, data: [DEBUG]}, {id: 9, parentId: 8, data: []}, {id: 10, parentId: 3, data: [ERROR, ERROR]}]

const tree = buildTree (items)
const newTree = calculateStatus (tree)

// stringify just to avoid SO's /**id:N**/ & /**ref:N**/ notation.  Statuses ARE references
// Note that `tree` was not modified in calling `calculateStatus`
console .log (JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4))
printTree (newTree)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`buildTree` is built atop `buildForest` which recursively scans the list of elements for the next set of children.  Note that this creates plain JS objects, and does not use something like your `Node` constructor.

`calculateStatus` builds a new node from a current one by first recurring on any children, extracting their `status` properties, and then calls `maxStatus` with them and the current node's status to derive the new status.  Then it creates a new node with those properties.  Note that other properties of the node than `children` and `status` will be shared by reference, if they are reference types.  (It doesn't matter with this example as `id` and `parentId` are primitives.  But it does show that this technique reuses as much as it can.)

Because it's being called with `map` and we add a default parameter, you cannot replace `node .children .map (c => calculateStatus (c))` with `node .children .map (calculateStatus)`, which certainly would feel cleaner.  If you don't like that default parameter, we could easily recast this as:

```js
const calculateStatus = (node) => {
  const children = node .children .map (calculateStatus)
  return {
    ...node,
    status: maxStatus ([node .status, ...children .map (c => c .status)]),
    children,
  }
}
```

I left `printNode`/`printTree` alone; they work fine with these plain JS objects.

---

You may not find this of use if you really prefer to mutate your data, but I find it a cleaner way to work.

### Update

It wasn't clear to me what was meant by this comment:

> I am going to throw the tree away, so mutating it would not be an issue.

But if it meant that the intermediate tree is of no value whatsoever, and is only there as a step to create the final tree, then we can build that final tree directly, with code something like this:

```js
const buildForest = (items, target) => 
  items .filter (({parentId}) => parentId == target) .map (
    ({id, parentId, data}) => {
      const children = buildForest (items, id)
      const status = maxStatus ([...data, ...children .map (c =>  c .status)])
      return {id, parentId, status, children}
    })

const buildTree = (items) => {
  const children = buildForest (items, 0)
  const status = maxStatus (children .map (c => c .status))
  return {id: 0, parentId: null, status, children}
}
```

Comment: I am going to throw the tree away, so mutating it would not be an issue. For a pure functional approach, yes--creating a derivative tree would be a better idea.

Comment: If that's the case, then is the intermediate tree used for nothing but calculating the final tree?  If so, then my update demonstrates an easier technique.